# PHP: Open zipped file by name (without extracting)

Tags: php, mysql, csv, zip

I have a .zip file with a .csv file in it. I wonder if I can use this .csv file somehow **without extracting it locally**. I know that `ZipArchive` class makes it possible to get file contents without extracting it, like this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('archive.zip');
$contents = $z->getFromName('file.csv');
```

That's nice, but I need to use it with MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` query, where I must provide file's name, not the contents.

I've heard about `zip://` protocol and I tried things like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'zip:///Library/WebServer/Documents/archive.zip#file.csv'
INTO TABLE `test`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(`column1`, `column2`);
```

But it doesn't seem to work here. Works fine for extracted .csv file, without `zip://` protocol.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just extract it to a temp file, LOAD DATA it and then delete the temp file?  What's wrong with that approach?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but I don't want to do any disc-related tasks here.

Comment: Plus, I'm learning new things :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify the `LOCAL` keyword, `LOAD DATA INFILE` instructs the **mysql server** to read a data file placed on the server. The mysql client (PHP) will not touch the file, it just sends the file name.

If you specify the `LOCAL` keyword, the mysql client will transfer the file from the client to the server, however still the server will read the file. unfortunately zip files aren't supported.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html